# How to disable "Pending kernel upgrade" message?

Tags: upgrade, 21.04

Since I upgraded to *Ubuntu 21.04 hirsute*, I get this *very* annoying message whenever I perform some upgrades.

[image: Pending kernel upgrade]

How to disable it? It's breaking my upgrade scripts.

---

System information :

```yaml
OS: Ubuntu 21.04 x86_64
Host: HP G62 Notebook PC 0598120000202710010020100
Kernel: 5.11.0-24-generic
Uptime: 17 mins
Packages: 1289 (dpkg), 11 (snap)
Shell: bash 5.1.4
Resolution: 1366x768
Terminal: /dev/pts/0
CPU: Intel i3 M 370 (4) @ 2.399GHz
GPU: Intel Core Processor
Memory: 424MiB / 3726MiB
```

Upgrade script :

```bsh
sudo apt update
sudo apt full-upgrade -y --auto-remove
sudo reboot now
```

Comment: What upgrades and how are you performing them?  Please edit your question with the output of `sudo apt update`.  What happens when you reboot?

Comment: I'm performing the upgrades available via `sudo apt full-upgrade -y --auto-remove` and performing them via `sudo apt full-upgrade -y --auto-remove`. When I reboot, the computer reboots. The results of `sudo apt update` depends on the upgrades available at the time. Example : *1 package can be upgraded. Run `apt list --upgradable` to see it.*

Comment: when you run apt commands with the `-y` flag you might be missing important information that could help explain the error.  Can you add the entire output of `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` into the body of your question.  If you put three backticks (`) before and after each block, it will retain monospace formatting and line breaks.

Comment: I think it would be better if you directly tell me what you're getting at. This is the normal upgrade process of Ubuntu Server and I would've included anything out of the ordinary to help you help me. Regardless, here's the logs of these commands : https://pastebin.com/BYsKWdr7
I would've put it in the question but `<details><summary>` doesn't seem to be supported here.

Comment: *"what you're getting at"* - problem solving which requires information gathering.  The error suggests that there is a problem somewhere with the package management and `apt` will usually throw errors or messages giving you more information.  I'm asking questions that might shed light on the problem, which could reveal a solution.  Have you already rebooted the system?  Also, do you generally, or have you ever manually installed kernel versions outside of the typical updates from the package manager or `apt`?

Comment: Also, why do you use a *script* for updates, and is there any reason you are using `sudo apt full-upgrade -y --auto-remove` instead of `sudo apt upgrade`?

Comment: Your output shows that you have the `-proposed` pocket of the Ubuntu Repositories enabled. That's generally a bad idea, and is one possible cause of your problem. Disable `-proposed`, run apt updates again, and see if the problem goes away over the next week or two.

Comment: Aight. I don't see any errors right now. The way I see it, it really looks like an intended notification suggesting that I reboot after the upgrade. I've dismissed this notification during many different upgrades before and I've already rebooted. This notification will likely appear during the next upgrade when a new kernel version will be available. I've never installed another kernel outside of what's available via upgrades. I also have this message on my Raspberry Pi running Ubuntu Server.

Comment: I've disabled `hirsute-proposed`, I'll see what happens next week. While it's nice if that solves it, it would be better to know how to disable only the prompt so it doesn't happen even if I use `-proposed` in the future, at least to actually answer the question.

Comment: To those that are pointlessly questioning the need for this rather than just answering the question it's not uncommon to need to create servers in an automated process such as virtual private servers and use a standard initializing script for each new server and the script will automatically restart anyway.

Answer (score 18):

This dialog is from 'autoremove'

To disable "Pending kernel upgrade" via command line:

```
vim /etc/needrestart/needrestart.conf
```

then uncomment this line

```
#$nrconf{kernelhints} = -1;
```

Or just replace them in one line:

```
sed -i "s/#\$nrconf{kernelhints} = -1;/\$nrconf{kernelhints} = -1;/g" /etc/needrestart/needrestart.conf
```

Comment: Thank you for that answer! I ended up putting that line into an `/etc/needrestart/conf.d/99mychanges.conf` file. This way I do not need to change an auto-installed config.

Answer (score 5):

A workaround is to remove `needrestart`:

```
sudo apt -y remove needrestart
```

Comment: While this may work, it also removes a useful program and is likely not what most users want. Benny's answer below is less invasive.

Answer (score 1):

Having encountered this myself, I think the actual best way to do ths would be to remove `needrestart` from the scripts run after `apt`. On Ubuntu, this would be `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99needrestart`.

Depending on what you want to do exactly, either deleting `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99needrestart` permanently or temporarily moving it in the upgrade script would be the best way of sorting this out. `needrestart` has some uses, after all, so removing it entirely may not be the best idea.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of removing system package, better approach would be to disable system upgrade.
To disable auto-upgrade via command line:

Open and edit the */etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades* using the bellow command:
`sudoedit /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades`

Change content **FROM:**
`APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists "1";
APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "1";`

**TO:**
`APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists "0";
APT::Periodic::Download-Upgradeable-Packages "0";
APT::Periodic::AutocleanInterval "0";
APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "1";`
Save File